# Data defined Style gives not same color in toc as on the canvas

Tags: qgis

QGIS 2.12.0 Lyon

I have an object with the following attributes:

- shape [QString] ...circle, square
- size  [integer] ...8, 10
- color [QString]

With the widget value map I fill these fields according to csv files.
My color file looks like:

```
 rgb;description
'215,12,16';red
'51,36,215';blue
```

I did a rule-based style and on the map canvas it just looks like it should. But the colors in legend (TOC) are the predefined colors from the page "rule properties". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a screenshot of your rule-based styles window.

Comment: It let me suppose bad things. Do I have create for each combination a diffrent rule? So it did not automatically add the properties like on the canvas to the TOC.

Comment: What kind of data is stored in the `farbe` attribute? RGB string or full color-name?

Comment: Attribute farbe is the same as color from the example above. So i insert an rgb-string from my color.csv file.

Comment: OK. Then, I see no other solution than setting up rules one by one for each combination...

Comment: Would there be a other solution if i use an integer for color and size.  I am at the start of my work and just look what kind of option QGIS supplies.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: That's currently not possible.

There have been discussions about how to automatically create legends for data-defined styles. There's a solution for data-defined size but none for data-defined color so far. I assume funding would be necessary since it's not a trivial issue.